# Why is the application secret required for extending a token lifetime?

Tags: facebook, access-token

My understanding of the application secret is that it is meant to be kept "secret".

I am wondering how I could extend the lifetime of a token using the client side flow without embedding the application secret in the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, you'll need to do it server side (maybe via proxying the call)

There should be few reasons to have a long term token in client code if it's Javascript, for example, and I believe the iOS and Android SDK's already receive extended tokens when they use the SSO flow

Comment: In this case I am running Javascript code in a desktop client. The client uses the Facebook token as an authentication credential towards my server. I guess the only way is to proxy the call. Thanks for the quick answer